# How to remove keylistener from an object( an image in my case used as label) when it has reached some particular co-ordinates?

Tags: java, swing, animation, keylistener

How to remove keylistener from an object (an image in my case used as label) when it has reached some particular co-ordinates ?

Comment: please post code what you have tried

Comment: you can see my code here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737706/trying-to-move-a-rectangle-with-the-help-of-arrow-keys-in-core-java-using-jframe 
I previously posted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess this is a continuation of your pervious question [Trying to move a rectangle with the help of arrow keys in Core Java using JFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737706/trying-to-move-a-rectangle-with-the-help-of-arrow-keys-in-core-java-using-jframe).

In your KeyAdapter where you move your label, after you have confirmed that your label is where it is supposed to, you can simply say:

```
l.removeKeyListener(this)
```

Note that you have to mark the label as `final JLabel` for this to work.

If the above complicates things, try creating a small helper class which extends the KeyAdapter, and put your code in it. This class can then take the label you want as a constructor argument, so that you have access to it at any time.

```
private static class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
    JLabel l;
    public MyKeyListener(JLabel label) {
        this.l = label;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
        // --- Do some stuff here
        // --- Realize that you are done (I.E. Label is in position)
        l.removeKeyListener(this)
    }
}
```

Then do

```
l.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener(l));
```

in your constructor.

Comment: Yes its working. Thanks. 
Actually I am trying to make an animation in which a ball falls from a tall crane and then it its some spring on ground and bounces back back again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to make, but this may help you. Next time please add your code to a question.

```
KeyAdapter instance = new MyKeyAdapter();
label.addKeyListener(instance);
 ......
 ......
if(reached()){
    label.removeKeyListener(instance);
}
```

Comment: You can see my code here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737706/trying-to-move-a-rectangle-with-the-help-of-arrow-keys-in-core-java-using-jframe
And yes, what you suggested is working. Thanks. :)